# How to write test case Drawer layout in Robotium

Tags: android, testing, android-listview, robotium, drawerlayout

I am using DrawerLayout in a Activity and i have to write test cases for that in Robotium:
1) How to check if drawerlaout is open or closed i tried but it is not working below is the code I have written in Robotium:

```
    public void testOpenAndCloseNavigationDrawer() {
          /* DrawerLayout drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);*/

           DrawerLayout drawer = ((BalanceActivity)activity).mDrawerLayout;
           assertFalse(drawer.isActionbarDrawerOpened());
           solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
           assertTrue(drawer.isActionbarDrawerOpened());
           solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
           assertFalse(drawer.isActionbarDrawerOpened());
    }
```

2) I have two listviews in Activity one is the main listview another is the listview in  drawerlayout, I am able to test the main listview item below is the test code i have written in Robotium for main listview:

```
    public void testNavigationToSubScreens() throws Exception {
            this.solo.waitForActivity(DetailActivity.class);  
            assertEquals(DetailActivity.class, solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass());  
            solo.clickInList(1);
            solo.goBack();
            solo.clickInList(2);
            solo.goBack();
            solo.clickInList(3);
            solo.goBack();
            solo.clickInList(4);
            solo.goBack();
    }
```

3) How to test listView items if we don't know how many items in listView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
public void testOpenAndCloseNavigationDrawer() {
    DrawerLayout drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final com.quisk.quiskapp.utils.DrawerLayout drawer = ((BalanceActivity)activity).mDrawerLayout;
    assertFalse(((BalanceActivity)activity).mDrawerLayout.isActionbarDrawerOpened());
    solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
    solo.waitForView(DrawerLayout.class);
    assertTrue(solo.waitForText("NOTIFICATIONS"));
    ListView listView = (ListView) solo.getView(R.id.left_drawer);
    View listElement = listView.getChildAt(1);
    solo.clickOnView(listElement); 
}
```